# Store short videos in Database

Tags: mysql, database, video, filepath

I am working on an application that plays audio and video clips. I've read other posts that recommend storing the index to the video file in the database and not the video itself. However, right now the biggest video I have is around 1MB and I have around 10 videos right now. Would I be better off just by storing the actual videos in the database. I also have text instructions that appear on the screen. Should I store the text directly in the database or have indexes pointing to their files?

Comment: that's up to you. there's very few usage cases that make files-in-database be an advantage, and the "it's a bad idea" list is invariably much longer than the "good idea" list.

Comment: Can you explain some of the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely up to you, however, the advantage of not storing the binary (file) in the database is that you can use other servers to serve the video. This often results in faster loading times (file servers are optimized to serve media, see http://cloudflare.com ), reduced load on your database (even though it's just 1MB), etc.

Another point, is that if you're storing the binary on your database, when you're sending the data/video to the client/user you'll usually have to set the headers and mime types so that the client knows how to display the video. It's not difficult to do, but it's just extra work (maintenance, and possible trouble-shooting areas in the future) that's already done for you that you don't need to do/worry about when you use a file/media server.

The database is best for information query, so I think it's best to store the text and indices on there and put your video elsewhere. It may help you when you get a bit more complicated or have more videos to manage.